# Automatic enumeration of an Sequence

Tags: f#, sequences

Is there standard function to enumerate an F# sequence that works like Python's [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

It's very easy to write from scratch:

```
let enumerate (sq : seq<'T>) = seq {
    let rec loop (e : IEnumerator<'T>) index = seq {
        if e.MoveNext() then 
            yield (index, e.Current)
            yield! loop e (index+1) 
    }

    use enum = sq.GetEnumerator()
    yield! loop enum 0
    }
```

but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

PS: also, I tried

```
let seasons = ["Spring"; "Summer"; "Fall"; "Winter"]
for x in Seq.zip [0..100000] seasons do
    printfn "%A" x
```

but this `[0..10000]` part looks ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think maybe you want `Seq.mapi` or `Seq.iteri`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340431.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370541

Comment: Thanks. At least, `Seq.mapi` can do what I want as one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
module Seq =
    let inline enumerate source = Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i,x) source

> ["a"; "b"] |> Seq.enumerate;;
val it : seq<int * string> = seq [(0, "a"); (1, "b")]
```

Or Hot 'n Spicy with FSharpx:

```
let enumerate source = Seq.mapi (curry id) source
```

Well, actually, in FSharpx it's already available as `Seq.index`.